# RSS feed site image custom resolution

Tags: rss, thumbnails, feed

I want to update the resolution of my site image for my RSS feed. Right now it is 32px. How can I update the resolution without plugins?

```
<image>
    <url>https://evenwerk.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/cropped-logo-32x32.png</url>
    <title>Evenwerk</title>
    <link>https://evenwerk.com</link>
    <width>32</width>
    <height>32</height>
</image>
```

Answer (score 0):

Head to **Settings >> Media.** Here, you will find the option for changing the dimensions for your thumbnails. Update it according to your need.