# Change the RSS feed image

Tags: images, rss, feed

I want to customize this part of Wordpress feeds:

```
<image>
<url>https://[example.com]/wp-content/uploads/cropped-logo-32x32.png</url>
<title>My Site</title>
<link>https://example.com</link>
<width>32</width>
<height>32</height></image>
```

There is a similar question with a wrong answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/321458/rss-feed-site-image-custom-resolution). Changing media settings in wp-admin does not work.

I would like to change the image size or customize the entire part with a custom image URL for example.

Thank you

Comment: Every other answer I can find is for individual posts. Someone please provide an answer to set the image for the entire feed.